# target=_blank for links in view

Tags: views, navigation

I've got a view and one of the fields is displayed as a link. (`Output this field as a link` is cheked). But now i want those links to have `target=_blank` attribute.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

When you check `Output this field as a link` there is a `Target` input box available (Further down). In that input box you can write `_blank`. (D7)

Answer (score 2):

edit: I just saw the answer whitefleaCH gave you - I never use the output settings as i prefer to style my views using templates to clean up the code - so i didn't know that option existed, though I presumed it did..

---

You can either use the themeing part of view and create your own template for the row style and simply hardcode the link attribute into it there (click the 'theme: information' part in the advanced settings of your view to see how to name your theme template).

Or which is probably easier - depending on how much themeing you'll be doing to your view - is to use jquery by doing the following:

Create a .js file and paste the following in into it (create a new textfile and save as yourfile.js):

```
(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {

      $('.CLASS a[href]').attr({
          target: "_blank", 
          title: "Opens in a new window"
        })

});

}(jQuery));
```

Change the CLASS bit with the class surrounding your link and save the file.

Upload your YOURFILE.js to your theme directory (eg: sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/)
Open YOURTHEME/template.php file and tell it to load your .js file by adding the following line

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOURTHEME').'/assets/js/YOURFILE.js');
```

Clear your cache and all links surrounded by

```
  <div class="CLASS"><a href="">Link</a></div>
```

will automatically open in a new window.

Of course you can do a lot more with the above script, like add a special class to the links so you can use .css to style them differently, or append some symbol or image etc etc ...

I hope this helps.

Comment: "CLASS"? What an "imaginative" name! :D Btw. target="_blank" causes XHTML Strict-validation problems, so maybe your method is the right one instead of "burning" it into the HTML-output.

Comment: haha, yes, I was trying to be clear as there is a dot before it ;-)

Comment: don't think JS is ever a good option for this

Answer (score 1):

[Linked Field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/linked_field) with Tokens.

Just brilliant!

[image: Using of the Linked Field module example]

After that in your View you may select **Show:Content | Teaser**
(Teaser or any other preferable display)

The same but kinda verbose way give us the [Image Link Formatter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_link_formatter), but only for images.

@whitefleaCH gives good solution too! (only for Views module)