# "_blank" target attribute for links in views

Tags: views

I have a custom view that lists a specific content type. I have fields output for each node and have set them to "Link to: Content".

Simply, is there a way to now set the target to "_blank"?

If you are "Rewriting Results" you have the option to specify the target attribute, however I am not rewriting the result (this requires a separate declaration of link path).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this requires a separate declaration of link path

If you are talking about node title it doesn't require a declaration of link path. Just leave this field empty and link will be made with default link path (e.g. node/NID).

For other fields you need to override link path. The easiest way is to add *nid* field and exclude it from display. Then you can use `node/[nid]` as link path. In this case you need not use link formatter in field settings.

Comment: Hey @Xio tried this checking "Rewrite the output of this field" and "Output this field as a link" and defining "target", however it doesn't apply _blank.

Comment: What version of the Drupal are you using? It isn't required to check "Rewrite the output of this field" checkbox.

Comment: Hey @Xio, using 7. Thanks for your help. Am I looking in the wrong place? I've attached a screenshot of the area. Target option only becomes available when I check  "Output this field as a link" under rewrite results. Seems odd that I need to rewrite results when the field is already linked to Content. It also says "If checked, this field will be made into a link. The destination must be given below."

Comment: I was thinking you are asking about node title. For other fields "Link path" is really required. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Xio. Might be worth adding to change dropdown "Link image to:" to "nothing". Else it appeared to interfere with the rewrite link.

Answer (score 0):

I think more comfortable approach is the answer "[target=_blank for links in view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15203/target-blank-for-links-in-view/164425#164425)"

1. By using [Linked Field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/linked_field) (or one other) and the teaser display in View (Show:Content | Teaser)

[image: Using of the Linked Field module example]

2. By using and configuring fields in View module (not any content's display).